# Pass array pointer to function expecting type interface

Tags: pointers, go, slice

An example in a Golang book shows a pointer to an array being passed into a function by reference:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func reclassify(planets *[]string) {
    *planets = (*planets)[0:8]
}


func main() {
    planets := []string{
        "mercury", "venus", "earth", "mars", "jupiter",
        "saturn", "uranus", "neptune", "pluto",
    }
    reclassify(&planets)
    fmt.Println(planets)
}
```

I tried to replace the *[]string argument to reclassify() with an interface:

```
func reclassify(planets interface{}) {
    *planets = planets.(*[]string)[0:8]
}
```

However I get these errors:

```
./test.go:10:2: invalid indirect of planets (type interface {})
./test.go:10:32: cannot slice planets.(*[]string) (type *[]string)
```

I have used the interface before to pass different data types into a given function. Is it possible to do it for this example in a similar manner?

I can see that my version's *planets variable doesn't make sense but I'm not sure what to change it to, if anything.

Comment: Use this code: `*(planets.(*[]string)) = (*planets.(*[]string))[0:8]` ([run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hcRc7jDX67Y))

Comment: interface{} does not mean „any type“ ist means just interface{}. Take the Tour of Go. (What you seem to try does not work). Stop using the empty interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll recommend to use type assertion to determine the type and update it. `interface` in Golang is just an interface.

```
func reclassify(planets interface{}) {
    switch v := planets.(type) {
        case *[]string:
            fmt.Println("Slice string:",*v)
            *v = (*v)[0:8]
        default:
            fmt.Println("Uknown")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would use this if actually putting into a real program. Cerise Limon’s example is what I was attempting though.